# Multiple text Alignments in UITextView (iOS 4 compatible)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, core-text, text-alignment

I need to use Multiple textAlignments in single `UITextView` i.e. one para LeftAligned and other Para Right.

I achieved this using `NSMutableAttributedString` but that's only for iOS 6 as it's crashing on devices with older OS. I am looking for some solution which works on previous `iOS` versions too. Ideally `iOS4.3` compatible solutions. I had checked several solutions uploaded on SO here but couldn't find which does set multiple alignments to be exact. May be due to my little knowledge regarding core text, I am unable to use it. Some specific help with sample code will help much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are only displaying the text (without editing), you could use a UIWebView and CSS for text styling.

Comment: I had to use a custom font for the Text displayed in it. Can I use that Custom font with CSS and HTML styling? Can you please give me some code or links to examples?

Comment: Check out this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html)

Comment: I am gonna give it a try.. do you think it'll look similar to a uitextView. I've to make it's BG clearColor?

Comment: You can make it look like a native field with the CSS, if the above method works. I don't know if it is enough to set the backround color to `clearColor`, you may have to do something in the HTML code too (something like transparent background color or no backround)